# Запись во внутреннее хранилище Android Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

Пишу пробное приложение, простой рекордер стрима со штатной камеры и запись в .mp4. Как можно организовать запись во внутреннее хранилище Android устройства. С внешней памятью (SD Card) нет проблем, там можно выставить манифест. Пишу все в VS 2017. Собственно код:

```
[Activity(Label = "videoFaceDetect", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    MediaRecorder recorder;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Установка основного экрана
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var record = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Record);
        var stop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Stop);
        var play = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Play);
        var video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);

        string path = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies  + "/test.mp4";

        record.Click += delegate 
        {
            video.StopPlayback();

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
            recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
            recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
            recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
            recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
            recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);
            recorder.Prepare(); // Вот в этом месте приложение выдает exeption;
            recorder.Start();
        };


        stop.Click += delegate 
        {
            if (recorder != null)
            {
                recorder.Stop();
                recorder.Release();
            }
        };

        play.Click += delegate 
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
            video.SetVideoURI(uri);
            video.Start();
        };


    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        if (recorder != null)
        {
            recorder.Release();
            recorder.Dispose();
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Exeption]

Камера при нажатие на кнопку "Запись" даже не стартует.

Comment: хочется конечно дать ссылку на готовый проект камеры, но сначала спрошу, а Вы проверяли наличие файла? System.IO.FileInfo

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, но получилось после добавления прав в манифест приложения на работу с внешним хранилищем.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Поле этого удалось записать файл во внутреннюю память планшета.